# Неправильно двигаются изображения по таблице

Tags: javascript

Делаю задачу в js, муравьи должны двигаться из муравейника каждую секунду одновременно до стульев. При достижении точки назначения меняться картинка. 
В коде заменил муравейник черным цветом, муравьев красным, стулья синим и при достижении становится зеленый цвет.

Нужные данные о коде:

`anthill` - муравейник откуда выходят муравьи

`st` - содержит `xs` `ys` координаты стула, `xa` `ya` координаты муравья, `curtime` при 1 меняет картинку на `antchair` (муравей достиг точки), `show: f` метод)

Функция `f(t)` - `t` у нас это секунда, `count` туда вносится. `t1` манхэттенское расстояние. `tx` `ty` расстояние между муравьем и стулом по `x` и `y`, `txa` `tya` не помню. Ниже если совпали координаты стула и муравья, то `curtime = 1`, если нет то по горизонтали сначала движем муравья, затем по вертикали.

Функция `page()` связана с кнопкой "Прибавить секунду", там `count` прибавляется и каждый муравей и стул прогоняется через `f(t)` с текущим `count` и затем таблица перерисовывается. Вот там где должно прогоняться начинается вся проблема.

```
for(var m=0; m<st.length; m++)
    st[m].show(count);
```

`isNatural` - просто проверяет введена ли цифра, а не что-либо ещё (вроде как)

`newGame` - как-то там настраивает ширину высоту и создает поле через `createField`

Функция `createField` создает таблицу, а так же проверяет клетки через цикл на наличие там стула муравья муравейника и муравья достигнувшего точку

Функция `restart` запускается в начале, очищает поле (ну по идее должно, но не очищает :)),  берет ширину и высоту заданную (по умолчанию 10х10) и запускает функцию `newGame`

**Суть проблемы:** муравьи двигались нормально, когда я рисовал таблицу без `create element`, а через `document.write` с использованием `localStorage` и вносил туда count (секунды), обновлял страницу и вносил значение из хранилища в `count` и пересчитывал через функцию `f(t)`

Теперь же я пытаюсь сделать более прилично, функция `f(t)` осталась, `count` при нажатии на кнопку прибавляется нормально, идет пересчет в `f` функции, затем таблица рисуется через функцию `createField`, но почему-то муравьи двигаются сначала на правильную точку (если `count = 1`, то на первую секунду, если `count = 2` то на вторую как надо и т.д.), но при нажатии ещё раз прибавить секунду муравей ходит не на одну клетку вперед, а на две, при нажатии ещё раз на 3, затем на 4, на 5 и т.д.

`count` остается таким же, как видно в поле "Секунда"
В чем может быть проблема? Из-за чего так считается и как это исправить? 
Причем, если `count` сделать равной 1 в функции `page()`, а затем нажимать прибавить секунду, то муравьи ходят нормально, а count при этом останется равным 1

```js
var count = 0;
var anthill = [{
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}];
var st = [{
    xs: 4,
    ys: 2,
    xa: anthill[0]['x'],
    ya: anthill[0]['y'],
    curtime: 0,
    show: f
  },
  {
    xs: 1,
    ys: 7,
    xa: anthill[0]['x'],
    ya: anthill[0]['y'],
    curtime: 0,
    show: f
  },
  {
    xs: 7,
    ys: 8,
    xa: anthill[0]['x'],
    ya: anthill[0]['y'],
    curtime: 0,
    show: f
  },
  {
    xs: 9,
    ys: 9,
    xa: anthill[0]['x'],
    ya: anthill[0]['y'],
    curtime: 0,
    show: f
  },
  {
    xs: 5,
    ys: 2,
    xa: anthill[0]['x'],
    ya: anthill[0]['y'],
    curtime: 0,
    show: f
  }
];





function f(t) {
  var t1 = Math.abs(this.xs - this.xa) + Math.abs(this.ys - this.ya);
  //время до стула
  var tx = this.xs - this.xa;
  var txa = Math.abs(tx);
  //время по x
  var ty = this.ys - this.ya;
  var tya = Math.abs(ty);
  //время по y
  if (t >= t1) {
    this.xa = this.xs;
    this.ya = this.ys;
    this.curtime = 1;
  } else if (tx > 0 && t <= txa)
    this.xa += t;
  else if (tx < 0 && t <= txa)
    this.xa -= t;
  else if (t1 > t) {
    this.xa += tx;
    this.ya = ty > 0 ? this.ya + (t - txa) : this.ya - (t - txa);
  }
};

function page() {
  count++;
  for (var m = 0; m < st.length; m++)
    st[m].show(count);
  document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = 'Секунда: ' + count;
  field = createField(rowsNumber, columnsNumber);
  fieldplace.append(field);
  setOnCenter(field);
}

restart();

function restart() {

  if (isNatural(height.value) && isNatural(width.value)) {
    fieldplace.innerHTML = '';
    rowsNumber = height.value;
    columnsNumber = width.value;
    newGame(rowsNumber, columnsNumber);

  }
}

function newGame(rowsNumber, columnsNumber) {
  fieldplace.style.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth - 16 + 'px';
  fieldplace.style.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight - info.getBoundingClientRect().bottom -

    8 + 'px';
  fieldplace.innerHTML = '';
  var field = createField(rowsNumber, columnsNumber);
  fieldplace.append(field);
  setOnCenter(field);

}

function setOnCenter(elem) {
  var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  var height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
  var width = rect.right - rect.left;
  elem.style.top = Math.max(0, (document.documentElement.clientHeight - height) / 2) + 'px';
  elem.style.left = Math.max(0, (document.documentElement.clientWidth - width) / 2) + 'px';
}

function isNatural(text) {
  return +text > 0 && ((~~+text) == +text);
}

function createField(height, width) {

  var field = document.createElement('table');
  var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  field.append(tbody);
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      let td = document.createElement('td');
      for (var m = 0;

        m < st.length; m++) {
        if (st[m][`xs`] == i && st[m]

          [`ys`] == j)
          td.className = "chair";
        if (st[m][`xa`] == i && st[m]

          [`ya`] == j)
          td.className = "ant";
        if (anthill[0][`x`] == i && anthill

          [0][`y`] == j)
          td.className = "anthill";
        if (st[m][`xs`] == i && st[m]

          [`ys`] == j && st[m][`curtime`] == 1)
          td.className = "antchair";
      }
      row.append(td);
    }
    tbody.append(row);
  }
  field.className = 'field';
  field.dataset.columns = width;
  field.dataset.rows = height;
  return field;
}
```

```css
td {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

td.anthill {
  background-color: black;
}

td.chair {
  background-color: blue;
}

td.ant {
  background-color: red;
}

td.antchair {
  background-color: green;
}

#fieldplace {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.field {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="info">

  <input type="button" VALUE="Прибавить секунду" onClick="page()">
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Перезапуск" onclick="restart()">
  <label>Высота: <input type="text" id="height" value="10"/></label>
  <label>Ширина: <input type="text" id="width" value="10"/></label>
  <label id="min">Секунда: 0</label>
  <hr>
  <div id="fieldplace"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема кроется в логике расчёта координат

```
  if (t >= t1) {
    this.xa = this.xs;
    this.ya = this.ys;
    this.curtime = 1;
  } else if (tx > 0 && t <= txa)
    this.xa += t;
  else if (tx < 0 && t <= txa)
    this.xa -= t;
  else if (t1 > t) {
    this.xa += tx;
    this.ya = ty > 0 ? this.ya + (t - txa) : this.ya - (t - txa);
  }
```

Эта функция высчитывает положение объекта от времени. Если объект не достиг цели Вы смещаете его не на 1 клетку, а на количество тактов(время). За это отвечают строки `this.xa += t;`, `this.xa -= t;` и `this.ya = ty > 0 ? this.ya + (t - txa) : this.ya - (t - txa);`
Кроме того, если объект не достиг цели за определённое количество таково, то он у вас "прыгает". Это происходит в первой части логической цепочки

```
  if (t >= t1) {
    this.xa = this.xs;
    this.ya = this.ys;
    this.curtime = 1;
  }
```

Когда Вы хранили данные в localStorage, похоже, что вы не сохраняли текущее положение и все расчёты велись с координат 0,0.
Вам ни к чему использовать "время" в определении новых координат. Делайте при каждом тике смещение на одну клетку.